# Jquery and CSS not loading reliably

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

EDIT: I have done some troubleshooting to help and try determine where the problem may lay... If the "personal" link is clicked and personal/personal.html allowed to follow through as a normal link would it executes flawlessly every time. The problem seems to be from the insetting of /personal/personal.html into the #content_container of index.html... Firefox seems to be more temperamental than chrom with this issue. /Edit

Live Example: http://www.dstpc.ca/Beta/index.html

I am using a premade Tabs JQuery and CSS file to accomplish the look and functionality I am seeking.

So far I have been able to reference the JQuery and CSS files and replace the content of 1 div with an html document while sliding up or sliding down another div to which causes a bottom boarder to be drawn or erase depending on the link followed.  These actions below happen without fail, consistently accurately.

What is happening is that "personal.html" will occasionally and unpredictably not properly call to the JQuery or CSS file. So that there are no tabs or formatting just black text in headings and div's. I will add that the first load works pretty much every time but I would like to avoid a simple refresh method so that data stays a low as possible and speed is fast. I find that subsequent clicks between "Home" and "Personal" to test functionality follow no rhyme to my reason as to when or if it will call the JQuery or CSS file.

Sometimes I see when "personal.html" is loading in the midst of the transition the HTML version loads and I can see the plain text but then the document calls the JQuery and CSS and it snaps into format. I am wondering if this is the main issue? Would delaying the content from loading until after the page formatting is called and the scripts are ran could resolve the issue. If so how would I implement that solution?

I have included the Responsive Tab JQuery document I am referencing. If more code or sources are needed please let me know and I will add them. personal.html is also included.

My own JQuery script:

```
    $(".home_button").live('click', function() {
     $("#content_container").load("./index.html #drill_banner")
  $("#info").slideDown(1000, function() {
        $("menu").css("border-bottom", "#F93 2px Solid")
     })

     return false;  
    });

    $(".personal_info").live('click', function() {
     $("#content_container" ).load("personal/personal.html")
  $("#info").slideUp(1000, function() {
       $("menu").css("border-bottom", "#F93 0px Solid")
      })

     return false;
    });
```

personal.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/responsive_tabs.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">

    </head>

    <body>
<div class="responsive-tabs">
    <h2>Personal Technology Services</h2>

    <h2>On-Site</h2>
    <div>This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. This is a body of text. 
    </div>
    <h2>In-Shop</h2>
    <div> 
    Content for Tab 3 
    </div>

    <h2>
    Remote Service</h2>
    <div> 
    Content for Tab 3 
    </div>
</div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js">          
    </script>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js">   
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/responsive_tabs.js">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/script.js">
    </script>


    <script>
    $(function() {
    RESPONSIVEUI.responsiveTabs();
    })
    </script>    

    </body>
    </html>
```

Responsive Tabs JQuery

```
    /* ----------------
    ResponsiveTabs.js
    Author: Pete Love | www.petelove.com
    Version: 1.10
    ------------------- */

    var RESPONSIVEUI = {};

    (function($) {

    RESPONSIVEUI.responsiveTabs = function () {
    var $tabSets = $('.responsive-tabs');

    if (!$tabSets.hasClass('responsive-tabs--enabled')) {   
    // if we haven't already called this function and enabled tabs
    $tabSets.addClass('responsive-tabs--enabled');

    //loop through all sets of tabs on the page
    var tablistcount = 1;

    $tabSets.each(function() {

    var $tabs = $(this);

    // add tab heading and tab panel classes
    $tabs.children(':header').addClass('responsive-tabs__heading');
    $tabs.children('div').addClass('responsive-tabs__panel');

    // determine if markup already identifies the active tab panel for this set of tabs
    // if not then set first heading and tab to be the active one
    var $activePanel = $tabs.find('.responsive-tabs__panel--active');
    if(!$activePanel.length) {
    $activePanel = $tabs.find('.responsivetabs__panel').first().addClass('responsive-tabs__panel--active');
    }

    $tabs.find('.responsive-tabs__panel').not('.responsive-tabs__panel--active').hide().attr('aria-hidden','true'); 
    //hide all except active panel
    $activePanel.attr('aria-hidden', 'false');
    /* make active tab panel hidden for mobile */
    $activePanel.addClass('responsive-tabs__panel--closed-accordion-only');

    // wrap tabs in container - to be dynamically resized to help prevent page jump
    var $tabsWrapper = $('<div/>', {'class': 'responsive-tabs-wrapper' });
    $tabs.wrap($tabsWrapper);

    var highestHeight = 0;

    // determine height of tallest tab panel. Used later to prevent page jump when tabs are clicked
    $tabs.find('.responsive-tabs__panel').each(function() {
    var tabHeight = $(this).height();
    if (tabHeight > highestHeight) {
    highestHeight = tabHeight;
    }
    });

    //create the tab list
    var $tabList = $('<ul/>', { 'class': 'responsive-tabs__list', 'role': 'tablist' });

    //loop through each heading in set
    var tabcount = 1;
    $tabs.find('.responsive-tabs__heading').each(function() {

    var $tabHeading = $(this);
    var $tabPanel = $(this).next();

    $tabHeading.attr('tabindex', 0);

    // CREATE TAB ITEMS (VISIBLE ON DESKTOP)
    //create tab list item from heading
    //associate tab list item with tab panel
    var $tabListItem = $('<li/>', {
    'class': 'responsive-tabs__list__item',
    id: 'tablist' + tablistcount + '-tab' + tabcount,
    'aria-controls': 'tablist' + tablistcount +'-panel' + tabcount,
    'role': 'tab',
    tabindex: 0,
    text: $tabHeading.text(),
    keydown: function (objEvent) {
    if (objEvent.keyCode === 13) { // if user presses 'enter'
    $tabListItem.click();
    }
    },
    click: function() {
    //Show associated panel

   //set height of tab container to highest panel height to avoid page jump
   $tabsWrapper.css('height', highestHeight);

   // remove hidden mobile class from any other panel as we'll want that panel to be open at mobile size
   $tabs.find('.responsive-tabs__panel--closed-accordion-only').removeClass('responsive-tabs__panel--closed-accordion-only');

    // close current panel and remove active state from its (hidden on desktop) heading
    $tabs.find('.responsive-tabs__panel--active').toggle().removeClass('responsive-tabs__panel--active').attr('aria-hidden','true').prev().removeClass('responsive-tabs__heading--active');

    //make this tab panel active
    $tabPanel.toggle().addClass('responsive-tabs__panel--active').attr('aria-hidden','false');

    //make the hidden heading active
    $tabHeading.addClass('responsive-tabs__heading--active');

    //remove active state from currently active tab list item
    $tabList.find('.responsive-tabs__list__item--active').removeClass('responsive-tabs__list__item--active');

    //make this tab active
    $tabListItem.addClass('responsive-tabs__list__item--active');

    //reset height of tab panels to auto
    $tabsWrapper.css('height', 'auto');
    }
    });

    //associate tab panel with tab list item
    $tabPanel.attr({
    'role': 'tabpanel',
    'aria-labelledby': $tabListItem.attr('id'),
    id: 'tablist' + tablistcount + '-panel' + tabcount
    });

    // if this is the active panel then make it the active tab item
    if($tabPanel.hasClass('responsive-tabs__panel--active')) {
    $tabListItem.addClass('responsive-tabs__list__item--active');
    }

    // add tab item
    $tabList.append($tabListItem);


    // TAB HEADINGS (VISIBLE ON MOBILE)
    // if user presses 'enter' on tab heading trigger the click event
    $tabHeading.keydown(function(objEvent) {
    if (objEvent.keyCode === 13) {
    $tabHeading.click();
    }
    });

    //toggle tab panel if click heading (on mobile)
    $tabHeading.click(function() {

    // remove any hidden mobile class
    $tabs.find('.responsive-tabs__panel--closed-accordion-only').removeClass('responsive-tabs__panel--closed-accordion-only');

    // if this isn't currently active
    if (!$tabHeading.hasClass('responsive-tabs__heading--active')){

    var oldActivePos,
    $activeHeading = $tabs.find('.responsive-tabs__heading--active');

    // if there is an active heading, get its position
    if($activeHeading.length) {
    oldActivePos = $activeHeading.offset().top;
    }

    // close currently active panel and remove active state from any hidden heading
    $tabs.find('.responsive-tabs__panel--active').slideToggle().removeClass('responsive-tabs__panel--active').prev().removeClass('responsive-tabs__heading--active');

    //close all tabs
    $tabs.find('.responsive-tabs__panel').hide().attr('aria-hidden','true');

    //open this panel
    $tabPanel.slideToggle().addClass('responsive-tabs__panel--active').attr('aria-hidden','false');

    // make this heading active
    $tabHeading.addClass('responsive-tabs__heading--active');

    var $currentActive = $tabs.find('.responsive-tabs__list__item--active');

    //set the active tab list item (for desktop)
    $currentActive.removeClass('responsive-tabs__list__item--active');
    var panelId = $tabPanel.attr('id');
    var tabId = panelId.replace('panel','tab');
    $('#' + tabId).addClass('responsive-tabs__list__item--active');

    //scroll to active heading only if it is below previous one
    var tabsPos = $tabs.offset().top;
    var newActivePos = ($tabHeading.offset().top) - 15;
    if(oldActivePos < newActivePos) {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: tabsPos }, 0).animate({ scrollTop: newActivePos }, 400);
    }

    }

    // if this tab panel is already active
    else {

    // hide panel but give it special responsive-tabs__panel--closed-accordion-only class so that it can be visible at desktop size
    $tabPanel.removeClass('responsive-tabs__panel--active').slideToggle(function () {       $(this).addClass('responsive-tabs__panel--closed-accordion-only'); });

    //remove active heading class
    $tabHeading.removeClass('responsive-tabs__heading--active');

    //don't alter classes on tabs as we want it active if put back to desktop size
    }

    });

    tabcount ++;

    });

    // add finished tab list to its container
    $tabs.prepend($tabList);

    // next set of tabs on page
    tablistcount ++;
    });
    }
    };
    })(jQuery);
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: If you are struggling for answers cut it down your questions a little. There is a lot there for what is likely a simple problem :)

Comment: Here are 2 images I have screen capped to show you whats happening: The Desired Result is here - http://www.DSTPC.ca/Beta/TS/Desired_Result.png and here is the Undesired Result that appears to be happening http://www.DSTPC.ca/Beta/TS/Undesired_Result.png

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to allow listen for the `load()` to complete. eg in this snippet :

```
$("#content_container").load("./index.html #drill_banner", function() { 

  $("#info").stop().slideDown(1000, function() {
        $("menu").css("border-bottom", "#F93 2px Solid");
     });

});
```

---

Try that and see how it goes

Comment: * look to close statements with semi colons too , you have a few missing and that's just asking for trouble.

Comment: I have gone through and closed with semi-colons as recommended. I have also implemented the modified code from above. Unfortunately I see no discernible difference. I appreciate the help though. Thank You

Comment: okay @DSTPC, it was probally worth the clean up , and adding your `.slideDown()` function isnide the `.load()` callback is needed anyway. Sorry it didn't solve the problem. I will delete this answer soon to leave the question 'unanswered'

Comment: Just be sure Here are 2 images I have screen capped to show you whats happening: The Desired Result is here - http://www.DSTPC.ca/Beta/TS/Desired_Result.png and here is the Undesired Result that appears to be happening http://www.DSTPC.ca/Beta/TS/Undesired_Result.png –

Comment: Is that second image you selecting the text, or the text has a style of background-color:white ?

Comment: I am selecting text to show it has no formatting applied - because its all in black I wanted to make sure people could see what was happening

Comment: So all the page loading and animations work okay ? it's just a styling issue ? - are the styles that you want in the page that you are `.load()`ing in ?

Comment: Styling is provided by 2 css files General Style is provided by my own code: style.css and the responsive tabs is provided by the designer of the Jquery code: responsive_tabs.css. Upon a fresh load of the website whether it be entered by URL or by refresh if already on the page when you click "PERSONAL" the animations slide and the page calls for the JS and CSS file properly. IF at this time you hit home it pulls index.html #drill_banner back without refresh. Then if you hit "PERSONAL" agian it usally will not call the JS or CSS file leaving it with Raw formatting.

Comment: Are the CSS files in the page you are trying to `.load()` ?

Comment: If you are asking me if they are referenced in the markup of the page being loaded yes. in both personal.html and index.html all JS files (script.js and responsive_tabs.js) and CSS files (style.css and responsive_tabs.css) are referenced and do work the first time a user clicks "PERSONAL" its upon clicking "HOME" which just reloads #drill_banner back into #content_container within index.html that the problems starts

Comment: That's the problem. We wouldn't normally load CSS that way - - when you `.load('personal/personal.html')` into the `#content_container` it loads in the css. but when loading `load("./index.html #drill_banner")` you are only retrieving the content of the `#drill_banner` div and also replacing any content/css loaded in by `personal.html'. Can you include all the CSS you want into the main html document first ?

Comment: Forgive me I am having a problem following you on this one. index.html uses <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive_tabs.css"> This is all of the CSS I have as of this moment.

Comment: _"look to close statements with semi colons too , you have a few missing and that's just asking for trouble."_ ~ [**I seriously doubt the OP's problems are caused by any missing semi-colons.**](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/)

Comment: @DSTPC, when you load in `.load('personal/personal.html')` could you try just loading pat of it and see what happens ? - eg `.load('personal/personal.html #somedividonthepage')` - im only guessing as I can't see your setup but I think you are bringing in styles here when you do not want to.